# Can we use a variable which has endpoint URL directly in HTTP Request UIPath Activity?

Tags: uipath-studio, uipath-orchestrator

[image]

How to use a variable directly in **Http** Request Endpoint?

Comment: Yes, you can use with proper URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you close the activity configuration Wizard, your activity will still be there and you can fine tune the configuration freely in the Properties panel. In your case, configuring the Endpoint by using a variable.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdSrd.png)